# Docker run react-app image, but process exited early. Why?

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I used this dockerfile to build the image. Upon proceeding with docker run -p 3000:80 image_name, it returns this

```
docker run -p 3000:80 lifestyle-app

> lifestyle-report@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

(node:28) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
Starting the development server...

The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
```

I understood it had something to do with memory, **but my question is which memory,** because, if I ran npm start without docker, the react app is running just fine. Please help, thanks

Comment: memory ===== RAM

Comment: i understand memory = RAM, if that's the case, I shouldn't be able to npm start at the first place, (without the docker). But the issue is only when npm start is run through docker. So I assumes, if it's memory issue, it shouldn't be due to my pc memory.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with memory. Because you didn't specify `-d` in your command line to enable [detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d), Docker exited immediately after the the main npm process exited (`npm start` will create a subprocess to run your JS script). When Docker exits, it kills all the other processes in the container, including the subprocess running your script, thus the `kill -9` part in the error message. You should almost always run Docker apps with `-d` option, unless you only wish to execute a one-off command.

Just execute `docker run -d -p 3000:80 lifestyle-app`.

Comment: With or without `-d`, the container will exit when the single process running in it exits.  I'd normally expect `npm start` to keep running in the foreground and therefore keep the container alive on its own.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping. Tried adding detach into the command, but doesn't work. Only lasted about 10 seconds, and then exited again. Typed localhost:3000 on browser, yet no react page is rendered. Any suggestion to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi @gfek, this is a bug realted to react when it runs inside docker. I don't know if it is fixed now or not, but my workaround for that is to run your image with **-it** flag to keep your react app process running and receive requests